# Careers login redirects to a 404 error if original return URL had a query string

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, login, url-encoding

So, I had a message sent to me on Careers 2.0 today.  Since I didn't happen to be logged in there, clicking the inbox link took me to the following page:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2F185155%2Fmessages%2F438148%3Fnoredirect%3D1

So far, so good.  However, after logging in, I was redirected to the following page:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/185155/messages/438148%3Fnoredirect%3D1

which just says "*Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!*".

The problem is pretty obvious: the string `%3Fnoredirect%3D1` at the end of the return URL should've been URL-decoded to `?noredirect=1`.  Indeed, fixing it manually took me to the message I wanted to see in the first place.

Please fix the login process on Careers so that return URLs are properly percent-decoded.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to repro this but haven't been able to - if I'm logged out and click a messages link like yours, the noredirect parameter is correctly unescaped and I'm taken to the message as I expect.

Do you still get the problem if you try another browser?

Comment: No, and I can't repro it on Firefox either now. What's confusing me is that, when I try it now in different browsers, I'm seeing two different layouts for the login form -- some have the "Log in using OpenID" buttons on the left and the direct login form on the right, and some have them reversed. And neither of these layouts matches the page I remember seeing when I first reported this, which, IIRC, had no direct login form at all, just the buttons, like SO used to have before the login page redesign. Maybe there were some recent changes to the login process that caused and/or fixed this bug?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen it's all a consiparcy! (j/k - more likely your cache was over aggressive and kept old versions of pages :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Maybe, though they'd have to be *really* old; before this event, it had probably been months if not years since I last visited careers.SO. Anyway, I took some screenshots of the layouts I'm seeing now: [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gK42I.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ilta.png). The CSS seems to be identical, but the order of the forms in the HTML code is different.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I see you took them in different browsers, maybe they serve different CSS? Did you check it with dev tools?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes. The CSS is the same (AFAICT), the HTML is different. Reloading, even shift-reloading, doesn't change the layout. However, a consistent trend I'm seeing is that, in all three browsers I have (Firefox, Chromium and Opera), I get the buttons-on-right layout in incognito / private browsing mode, but the buttons-on-left layout in normal mode. I suspect there may be a cookie involved, but I haven't yet figured out which one. (Anyway, I'm not even sure this layout inconsistency has anything at all to do with the actual bug, it's just confusing me.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen weird and intriguing... guess only Alex here can dig in the server side code to shed some light over this. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Ps. The CSS certainly looks like it was designed with alternative layouts in mind, with contextual selectors like `#loginnew form + form` used to add a dividing space and border between the forms regardless of their order. I suspect there may be some kind of an [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) scheme going on here.

Comment: A/B testing for careers sounds interesting... hope @Alex here will take a look!